# How to send stdout of one Python program over UDP to stdin of another using BASH?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, udp

I'm running `foo.py` on Ubuntu box A, and I want to feed its `stdout` as `stdin` to `bar.py` running on Ubuntu box B.

I think `python foo.py | /dev/udp/12.34.56.78:1234` will send out of box A to box B, but how can I pick up the packets and feed them into `bar.py`?

I need something like `udp_listener localhost:1234 | bar.py` but (if that's correct) what's the actual syntax?

Comment: Try netcat (nc) or socat. For example with netcat just `nc -u -l 127.0.0.1 1234 | bar.py`. Note though that UDP is not a reliable protocol, i.e. packets might get lost, reordered, duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Ubuntu box B, run

```
nc -klu -p 1234 | cat
```

On your Ubuntu box A, run

```
echo "Hello world" > /dev/udp/12.34.56.78/1234
```

If this works, replace `cat` with `bar.py`
and replace `echo "Hello world"` with `python foo.py`

You may need to open firewall for boxB:1234/udp